# GROUP certain rows then GROUP BY a column

Tags: mysql, group-by, rows

I have a table name myrecord:

```
stu_name | gender | level
-------------------------
John     | Male   | Pre-Primary
Jane     | Female | Year 1
Sue      | Female | Year 2
```

I want to GROUP Year 1 and Year 2 as Primary. I've tried the following code but it's not working.

```
SELECT
SUM(gender = 'Male') male,
SUM(gender = 'Female') female,
(
substr(level, Year 1, Year 2) as Primary,  
substr(level, Pre-Primary) as Pre-Primary)
as level
FROM myrecord
GROUP BY level
```

The expected result would be:

```
Male | Female | level 
-------------------------
1    | 0      | Pre-Primary
0    | 2      | Primary
```

Is it possible to achieve that? I also tried to use CONCAT but it's not working either. I really need help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Query

```
SELECT SUM(t.Male) AS Male,
SUM(t.Female) AS Female,
t.level
FROM
((SELECT SUM(gender='Male') as Male,
SUM(gender='Female') as Female,
CASE WHEN level='Pre-Primary'
THEN 'Pre-Primary'
WHEN level LIKE 'Year%'
THEN 'Primary'
ELSE NULL END AS level
FROM myRecord
GROUP BY level) t)
GROUP BY t.level;
```

### [Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/bc93a/10)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
SUM(gender = 'Male') male,
SUM(gender = 'Female') female,
(  substr(level, Year 1, Year 2) as Primary,
substr(level, Pre-Primary) as Pre-Primary)  as level
FROM myrecord
GROUP BY level
```

You can use case to determine if this is male or female, and use count not sum to count the male on that level. Here is the query

**Not tested**

```
SELECT
(case when gender='male' then Count(select gender from table where gender='Male') else 0 end) male,
(case when gender='female' then Count(select gender from table where gender='female') else 0 end) female,
(  case when level='Pre-primary' then level else 'Primary' end) as Primary
FROM myrecord
GROUP BY level
```

Just let me know if there is error, i didn't test it

Comment: It didn't work. But is my substr() are in the correct form? Because I think that is where the problem came from but I just don't know how to think of other way to group that certain values.

Comment: yeah that's the error what is the purpose of that anyway?

Comment: I already solved the problem with the help of @Ullas. Anyway, thank you very much for your quick response. I really appreciate it so much :))

Answer (score 0):

please try the below

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN gender = 'MALE' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as Male, SUM(CASE WHEN gender = 'FEMALE' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as Female, CASE WHEN level='Primary' THEN 'Primary' ELSE 'Pre-Primary' END as newlevel FROM myrecord GROUP BY newlevel
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
SUM(gender = 'Male') AS male,
SUM(gender = 'Female') AS  female,
(case when(level = 'Year 1' OR level = 'Year 2' ) then 'Primary' else 'Pre-Primary' end) AS tempLevel

FROM myrecord
GROUP BY tempLevel
```

Here I use case statement for check the levels in myrecord table